# Django: Returning objects when using a generic relationship as a through model

Tags: django, m2m, generic-foreign-key

I have the following setup that i want to use to tag generic objects (at the moment just the one type, a resource object).

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    ...
    tag_items = GenericRelation(TaggedItem, related_query_name='resources')

    @property
    def platform(self):
        return self.tag_items.filter(relationship=TaggedItem.PLATFORM)

    @property
    def characteristics(self):
        return self.tag_items.filter(relationship=TaggedItem.CHARACTERISTICS)


class Tag(models.Model):
    ...


class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    # Relationship choices
    PLATFORM = 'platform'
    CHARACTERISTICS = 'characteristics'
    RELATIONSHIP_CHOICES = (
        (PLATFORM, 'Platform'),
        (CHARACTERISTICS, 'Characteristics'))

    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="%(class)s_items")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="%(class)s_tagged_items")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    relationship = models.CharField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_CHOICES, default=CHARACTERISTICS, max_length=50)
```

What i want is for `resource.platform/characteristics` to return a list of tag objects rather than the *through model* TaggedItem objects.

Can't quite figure out the best way to do it though. Any thoughts? Is this even a sensible approach?

Comment: object shouldn't be a field, it's a reserved keyword in python for datatype, you should change it to content_object or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    #...
    tag_items = GenericRelation(TaggedItem, related_query_name='resources')

    @property
    def platform(self):
        return Tag.objects.filter(
            taggetitem_items__resources=self,
            taggetitem_items__relationship=TaggedItem.PLATFORM,
        )

    @property
    def characteristics(self):
        return Tag.objects.filter(
            taggetitem_items__resources=self,
            taggetitem_items__relationship=TaggedItem.CHARACTERISTICS,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def characteristics(self):
    return Tag.objects.filter(pk__in=self.tag_items.filter(relationship=TaggedItem.CHARACTERISTICS).values('tag'))
```

Warning : Untested code, may not work but you get the idea.